# Addition and Direct Sums of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

**Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Prove or falsify the following:**

**a) If $A$ $+$ $B$ $=$ $A$ $+$ $C$, then $B$ $=$ $C$.**

**b)  If $A$ $⊕$ $B$ $=$ $A$ $⊕$ $C$ then $B$ $=$ $C$.**

I thought that a) was false since it is possible that B is a subset of $A$ and $C$ is a subset of $B$. This means that $B$ and $C$ need not be the exact same subspaces. In this case, either of the two subspaces ($B$ and $C$) will lead to a sum of $A$ with $A$.

For b), I thought it would be true because since the intersection of $A$ and $B$ and $A$ and $C$ will be $0$, then the only way to add the two subspaces and get the same result would be if $B$ equaled $C$.

But I am a little skeptical of my reasoning as I am not sure if the ideas of subspaces and subsets can be as easily interchanged as I have done above. I am also not sure if I have fully understood the idea of sums and direct sums of subspaces in this case.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) and b) are both  false: take $A=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb R\}$, $B=\{(0,y): y\in \mathbb R\}$, and $C=\{(x,x): x\in \mathbb R\}$. Then $A+B=\mathbb R^{2}=B+C$ but $B \neq C$. Also $A \cap B= A\cap C=\{0\}$. Remark: if the sum in b) denotes orthogonal sum then b) is true, but I don't think you are referring to orthogonal sums.

Answer (score 1):

a) and b) are false: take $V= \mathbb R^2, A=\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb R\}, B=\{(0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$ and $C=\{(x,x): x \in \mathbb R\}$.